# Python only integers, slices ... and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.optimize import fmin

Td=np.array([0.5,1,1.5,2,2.2,3,3.5,4,4.5,5])#time
findindex=lambda x:np.where(mt>=x)[0][0]
mindex=map(findindex,Td)

Zm=Td[mindex]
```

When I try to run this code it throws an exception.

Exception has occurred: IndexError
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

I am new in Python. 
Can someone help to solve this.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?what is `mt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to filter the index meet some criteria and then slice the numpy array using those indexes

```
mt=3
Td[np.where(Td<mt)] # where values in Td array less than mt get indexes and slice the array
```